# Ionic iOS app: Xcode UIKit Crashes

Tags: ios, xcode, ionic-framework, ionic2, testflight

Ionic iOS app is on testflight and I have 3 crashes (see below). They all have to do with the UIKit.

Since it is an Ionic app and I have nothing to do or have no control over layers and this stuff (all I can edit is the HTML, CSS, and JS for my ios app), I have no idea what in my code might be causing this or even where to start looking?

Any help or even just how to understand how the UIKit relates to my ionic code or point me in the right direction to look, would be appreciated, I am really stuck.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, do you have any leads on it?

Comment: I'm working diligently on it. I'll post an answer should I find something. Did you find a work around or has your project been on pause because of this?

Comment: I've ignored it after trying for a bit and hitting a wall since in all my testing I've only got this kind of UI kit crash a few times. Since it is ionic I  I am not familiar with the UI kit and errors at all. But I've hard core tested it and I don't get these too often and everything else works fine so really not sure what is going on. But, anything you can come up with would be much appreciated, since I basically got stuck with this, thanks!